# TypeError: unbound method mult() must be called with calculadora instance as first argument (got int instance instead)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get a 
***TypeError: unbound method mult() must be called with calculadora instance as first argument (got int instance instead)***

when running my python file :

```
    from __future__ import print_function

class calculadora:


    def suma(x,y):
        added = x + y
        print(added)

    def resta(x,y):
        sub = x - y
        print(sub)

    def mult(x,y):
        multi = x * y
        print(multi)


calculadora.mult(3,5)
```

Comment: Are you intended to try to create staticmethods here, or do you want instance methods?

Comment: @idjaw i want instance methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access methods as static methods(accesing methods without the clas instance), you need to decorate them with [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```
class calculadora:
    @staticmethod
    def suma(x, y):
        added = x + y
        print(added)

    @staticmethod
    def resta(x, y):
        sub = x - y
        print(sub)

    @staticmethod
    def mult(x, y):
        multi = x * y
        print(multi)
```

---

If you meant instance methods, you need to create instance first. and need to modify methods' signatures to include `self` as the first parameter:

```
class calculadora:
    def suma(self, x, y): # not `self`, refering class instance
        added = x + y
        print(added)

    def resta(self, x, y):
        sub = x - y
        print(sub)

    def mult(self, x, y):
        multi = x * y
        print(multi)


c = calculadora()  # Create instance
c.mult(3,5)  # Access the method through instance, (not class)
```

Comment: We don't know that for sure. Would be best to get clarification if they in fact want staticmethod or instance method.

Comment: @idjaw, The code doesn't specify `self.`, and not using instance variable at all. Also OP doesn't created any instance; So I thought it's all static methods. Anyway, I will add instance methods version too.

Comment: That is true. It can go either way to be honest :P

Comment: yeah i was trying to do something I read on a blog, but he had the code just like I wrote it on the question.  but I'm on python 2.7 and the tutorial was using python 3.x

Comment: @FidelCastro If you are using Python2.7, it is better to use new style classes: https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/